# Is there a C debugger for zOS?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, mainframe, zos

Is the a c debugger for zOS?  I know there is XDC, but I'm not really interested in the assembly.  I would rather have one that focuses on C.

Comment: c/XDC is now in beta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, IBM has a [`Debug Tool for z/OS`](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/debugtool/) which allows debugging at a higher level than assembler language.

I think it's separate from the `xlc` stuff so you'll have to pay for it but, since you're running a mainframe, that probably won't be an issue :-)

Comment: Thanks, I think this looks like the exact things I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [dbx](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/z/os/zos/features/unix/bpxa1dbx.html), which is part of Unix System Services, and thus included with z/OS.